# Trouble linking static libraries using Android NDK r5b

Tags: android, linker, static-libraries, android-ndk

Recently upgraded to NDK r5b, and the build fails with "undefined reference" to functions located in a static library.

Here is the error

```
/home/brian/workspace/VoiceEngineDemo/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/voiceenginejni/voice_engine_jni.o: In function `initVE':
/home/brian/workspace/VoiceEngineDemo/jni/voice_engine_jni.c:944: undefined reference to `VE_ADT_create'
```

It seem the link process is not loading the static module even though it is defined in the Android.mk as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE               := voiceenginejni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES            := voice_engine_jni.c printing.c jaudio.c etime.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS               := -D __arm  -D ANDROID -D USE_AEC_DEFAULTS -D USE_EC_DEFAULTS -D _DEBUG -D EC_VARIANT=EC_VARIANT_NEC -D AECG1_5_ENABLE

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES     := libvoiceengine libcpufeatures libaecg2

LOCAL_LDLIBS               := -llog -ldl    

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cpufeatures)
```

The VE_ADT_create function is located in libvoiceengine.a, which has been placed in the /obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ directory.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on this for me. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332679/cant-create-shared-library-with-static-inside

Answer (score 1):

Are you building the libraries using ndk-build?

If not, I usually keep libraries I've built with the standalone toolchain in the jni folder and reference them directly by name in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libvoiceengine.a
```

Comment: The static libraries are built using the "ndk-build" script, then the resulting .a are copied by a shell script into the /obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ directory.

Comment: hmm, another pitfall is accessing C functions from C++ without using extern "C" { ... }

Comment: All of our code is C code. Curiously, the exact same project setup builds without issue using the NDK 4rb.