# Can't create shared library with static inside

Tags: android, static, shared, android-ndk

Please help I search throw whole internet but I can't find answer ...

### C Layer

I have created simple function `int mean(int, int);` and place it in **calc_mean.h** and initialize it in **calc_mean.c** here are this two files.

#### calc_mean.c

```
#include "calc_mean.h"

int mean(int a, int b)  
{  
return (a+b) / 2;  
}
```

#### calc_mean.h

```
int mean(int, int);
```

Then I create make file and build archive (.a) file called Test_Archive.a using following make file

#### makefile

```
GCC := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
GPP := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe
AR  := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ar.exe

default: all

all: obj
    $(AR) r Test_Archive.a *.o

obj:
    $(GPP) -c *.c
```

I get **Test_Archive.a** archive file. Now I want to add this archive file to JNI and call `mean` function from my JNI project, for that I have created JNI and Java files which you can see below.

---

### JAVA Layer

How you can see here in java layer I have TestJavaClass that have one native method called `JMean` this method have two `int` arguments and return also `int`.

```
public class TestJavaClass
{
    /** Default Constructor
     * 
     */
    public TestJavaClass( ) {

    }

    /** Test Function. 
     *  
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    public native int JMean( int a, int b);
}
```

---

### JNI Layer

This is JNI header file

#### Test_Library.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX */

#ifndef _Included_com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX
#define _Included_com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
 * Class:     com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX
 * Method:    JMean
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX_JMean
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

#### Test_Library.c

```
#include "Test_Library.h"
#include "calc_mean.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX_JMean( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint a, jint b )
{
    return mean( a, b );
}
```

I put this two files **Test_Library.h**, **Test_Library.c** and **calc_mean.h**, **Test_Archive.a** and create make file **Android.mk**

#### Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := Test_Library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := Test_Library.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -LTest_Archive.a

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but when I want to create .so file, the following error occurs, why ?

> $ ../../ndk-build Compile thumb  : Test_Library <= Test_Library.c
>   SharedLibrary  : libTest_Library.so
>   C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/Fido/ProjectOSTX/obj/local/armeabi/objs/OSTX_Library/OSTX_Library.o:
>   In function `Java_com_Fido_OSTXLib_OSTX_JMean':
>   C:/cygwin/home/android-ndk-r5b/Fido/ProjectOSTX/jni/OSTX_Library.c:6:
>   undefined reference to`mean' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [/home/android-ndk-r5b/Fido/ProjectOSTX/obj/local/armeabi/libOSTX_Library.so]
>   Error 1

### Why undefined reference to `mean' ?

Comment: Dont you have to `#include "Test_Library.h"` in the Test_Library.c also?

Comment: no, Can you tell me there NDK gcc compiler is located ?

Comment: I think though, you have to include the header file wich you created using `javah` in your native code.

Comment: I have include it to Test_Library.c

Comment: Here is same question with no answer [check this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/f9669c71da2b3647)

Comment: I have successfully build your project here. I will post it as an answer how I did this.

Comment: Yes please place it I will try to do same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suppos the main reason was compiler settings, I make some modifications in ***makefile*** and my .a archive linked to shared library, here are modifications.

```
GCC := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
GPP := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe
AR  := C:\Tools\ndk-toolchain\ndk-standalone\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ar.exe

OPTIONS  :=\
-fpic \
-ffunction-sections \
-funwind-tables  \
-fstack-protector \
-D__ARM_ARCH_5__ \
-D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ \
-D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ \
-D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ \
-Wno-psabi \
-march=armv5te \
-mtune=xscale \
-msoft-float \
-mthumb \
-Os \
-fomit-frame-pointer \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-finline-limit=64 \
-DANDROID \
-Wa, \
-O2 \
-DNDEBUG \
-g \

default: all


all: obj
    $(AR) r libtestlibrary.a *.o

obj:
    $(GCC) $(OPTIONS) -c *.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to build the code successfully:

1. In your Eclipse Android Project create the folder `jni`.
2. Add the files `calc_mean.c; calc_mean.h; Test_Library.c and Android.mk` to the jni folder
3. Remove the line `#include "Test_Library.h"`from the Test_Library.c file. Everything else can stay as it is.
4. In the cygwin command line go to the root folder of your Eclipse Android project and run `ndk-build`

If you want to build your calc_mean also as static library during the ndk-build process then you can change your Android.mk file as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := Test_Archive
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := calc_mean.c

# compiler flags.
LOCAL_LDLIBS   = -lz -lm
LOCAL_CFLAGS   = -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -g

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := Test_Library
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Test_Archive
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test_Library.c


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: This is not a way, as in real I have no calc_mean.c and calc_mean.h files I have just calc_mean.a generated file ... so the main question is how I can add static (calc_mean.a) library to shared library ? The method you are talking about works only when you have calc_mean.c; calc_mean.h sources, but if I have only calc_mean.a how I must add it to shared library, can you help me ?

Comment: You can do this declaring the static library in your Android.mk file. `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := YOUR_STATIC_LIBRARIY`

Comment: What parameter ? I add `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Test_Archive.a` but nothing changes ....

Comment: I think the main reason of this is compilers, I think I must give some additional options when I compile Test_Archive.a, but what options I cant image ....

Comment: Leave the .a from the declaration just: `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Test_Archive`and remove also the `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -LTest_Archive.a`

Comment: if you want to creat the static library during the ndk-build then see the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply use C compiler instead!**

You compile with C++ compiler (Makefile has "$(GPP) -c *.c") and the function symbol name includes parameter information and is called different: not "mean", but something more complex, similar as Java names symbols internally. You can use "nm" to see what's inside an object file.

For example *my* g++ generates:

```
# nm x.o
00000000 T _Z4meanii
```

So there is no "mean" (but "Z4meanii"). Using a C compiler, and the symbol names are straightforward:

```
# nm x.o
00000000 T mean
```

(Please note that the same source code content was compiled)

So change in you Makefile:

```
obj:
    $(GCC) -c *.c
```

---

If for some reason a C++ compiler *must* be used, then extern "C" must be added:

**calc_mean.h** (simplified, without inclusion guards etc.)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int mean(int, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

In general, if you need C symbol names in C++ files, use extern "C". Test_Library.h uses it correctly and provides a nice example. You can put the same extern "C" logic (best including if #ifdef __cplusplus block) to your header file. Some consider it good practice to always do so.

But note that there are several, sometimes subtle, differences between C and C++, so I recommend to compile C sources with C compiler, although I know that there can be advantages using a C++ compiler.

oki,

Steffen

Comment: This is not related to the question, but $(GPP) sounds like C PreProcessor. I think it is better to use "CC=gcc" and "CXX=g++"