# libpcap static linking errors (undefined reference to pcap APIs) in Android NDK-build

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-linking, libpcap, android.mk

I am trying to run the [packetspammer](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/packetspammer) application on an Android nexus-7 wifi only tablet (code name: grouper). I downloaded the [libpcap](https://github.com/android/platform_external_libpcap) library and was able to generate the static library (libpcap.a). However, when I try to build the packetspammer app using NDK-build, I keep getting linker errors.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
packetspammer
|
jni
  |
  packetspammer source files
  Android.mk file that links in libpcap and builds the packetspammer binary
  <Directory>platform_external_libpcap 
       |
       libpcap.a file
```

Here is my android.mk file:

```
#Links the libpcap library
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := platform_external_libpcap/libpcap
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := platform_external_libpcap/libpcap.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := platform_external_libpcap
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#Builds packetspammer app
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := packetspammer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := radiotap.c packetspammer.c 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := platform_external_libpcap/libpcap.a
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ~/android/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-L/arch-arm/usr/include \
                ~/packetspammer/jni/platform_external_libpcap

TARGET_ARCH     := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

These are the error messages I get:

```
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_open_live'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_datalink'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_compile'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_geterr'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_setfilter'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_geterr'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_freecode'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_setnonblock'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_next_ex'
error: undefined reference to 'pcap_inject'
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with either the Android.mk file or with the process I follow. I looked at the NDK programmer's guide and followed the section "Building/Standalone toolchain" as well as "Building/Android.mk". I get the same linker error even with the standalone toolchain.

I found many posts that helped me solve several of my errors before I got stuck here. Here are the links to those:

[undefined reference error while statically linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209971/ndk-build-undefined-reference-to-errors-when-statically-linking-to-libxml-a);

[linking third party libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563928/linking-thirdparty-libs-libs-a-with-ndk);

[trouble linking static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173706/trouble-linking-static-libraries-using-android-ndk-r5b);

[using a pre-compiled static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463518/android-ndk-link-using-a-pre-compiled-static-library);

[libpcap for android](http://blog.umitproject.org/2011/05/libpcap-for-android.html);

[compile libpcap using android ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646344/compile-libpcap-using-android-ndk)

[porting JNetPcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952878/android-ndk-trying-to-port-jnetpcap)

Comment: maybe your libpcap.a is missing some header files that should cover the  undef fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. I followed the accepted answer in [this SO question (compile libpcap using android ndk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646344/compile-libpcap-using-android-ndk) and downloaded the libpcap from [this site](http://sourceforge.net/p/prueba-android/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jni/).

I compiled and built the libpcap.a static library, linked it in the packetspammer android.mk file and got the final executable.